# Como rodar Taiga.io no meu computador usando Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, localhost, webserver

Estou tentando rodar o [Taiga.io](https://taiga.io/) no meu computador. Toda a parte de *backend* funciona normalmente, mas quando tento acessar a URL `exemplo.com`, não funciona.

Estou usando: http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-production.html como tutorial.

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt, as perguntas devem ser feitas em **português**, se possível traduza a pergunta para que possa obter ajuda, recomendo que faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como o site funciona ;)

Answer (score 1):

"example.com" é uma URL válida na Internet, não aponta para o seu computador, (e não tem uma versão do Taiga backend rodando em example.com, que é um domínio reservado).  Para acessar o backend no seu computador tente trocar as configurações para `http://127.0.0.1:9001/` ou `http://localhost:9001/`.

Veja que os valores são usados como "exemplo" e não o que você deve colocar nos arquivos:

> Copy-paste the following config into ~/taiga-back/settings/local.py and **update it with your own details**

Comment: PS. eu respondi a sua pergunta - afinal, é uma dúvida simples, e não tem por que te deixar esperando - mas procure editar  traduzir sua pergunta para português, pra manter a consistência do conteúdo. Você pode criar outras perguntas direto em inglês em stackoverflow.com, se preferir (sem o .br)